# Java : HttpSession timeout filter check returns valid session object

Tags: servlets, weblogic, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0, httpsession

My Web App is purely JS app with crossroads js for routing.
For Login I'm using j_security_check FORM Auth and /LogOut servlet to invalidate session.

**Issue 1**
The real issue comes when the session is timed out, the login.html is rendered in part of the page with no css, with error 'Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html'

When using filter

```
<filter>
    <description>Session Timeout Filter</description>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
....
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

and JAVA code

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    try {
        req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        session = req.getSession(false);
        if (session != null && !session.isNew()){
            LOGGER.log("Session is Valid");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else{
            LOGGER.log("Session is Invalid");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/login.html?loggedOut=true").forward(request, response);
        }            
    } catch (Throwable t) {

    }

}
```

**Issue 2**
When the filter runs after say inactive 2-3 mins, it prints "Session is Valid". Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1:

When the session is invalid, the filter intercepts the requests and forwards to login.html. login.html includes a CSS file. So the browser sends an HTTP request for the CSS file. But you filter is mapped to `/*`. So it intercepts every request, including the one sent by the browser for the CSS file. And since the session is still invalid, the browser forwards the request, supposed to send a CSS file, to login.html.

Issue 2:

I don't know. Maybe your server uses a background thread cleaning timed out sessions every few minutes, and it hasn't bee executed yet, even though your very short timeout has elapsed. Or maybe the browser sends requests in the background that keep the session active.

Comment: For issue 1, I've included a check in the filter to continue to filter if the request is for login HTML and CSS. Even in that case the issue persists.